# CSS Menu not looking good with IE8

Tags: css, menu

For some reason my horizontal menu looks really bad on IE8 (and probably previous versions as well) (see first pic). No issue with latest version of safari, firefox and chrome (see second pic).
Any idea why and how to fix this? Site link http://goo.gl/nEx5e
Thanks

[image: Issue with IE8]

[image: Menu as it should look]

**CSS Code:**

```
#nav
{
    right:2%;
    list-style:none;
    position:fixed;
    /* float:right; */
    top:30px;
    z-index:1000;
    /* width:520px; */
}

#nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* dirty hack for IE7 */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

#nav a
{
    float:left;
    top:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:24px;
    color:#666;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#nav a:hover
{
    background:#dedede;
}

#nav .current a
{
    background:#666;
    color:#ededed;
```

Comment: Could you supply the HTML as well? Preferably in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: post a link or jsfidlle so we can encounter the problem though Images convey good message only when used for advertising :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you read my answer, you should consider that people will be less likely to answer your questions if you don't **accept answers** on the questions you post. This is generally considered rude.

Now... the problem is that you are using RGBA with transparency on the white button background.

IE8 and below can't handle transparent colors like that. You'll need to manually set transparency with `opacity: 0.x` and `filter: Alpha(opacity='xx')`.

Note that `opacity: 0.8` is equal to `filter: Alpha(opacity=80)`.

```
#nav a
{
    float:left;
    top:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:24px;
    color:#666;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: white;           // <------ !
    opacity: 0.8;                // <------ !
    filter: Alpha(opacity='80'); // <------ !
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: @Greg - You should also be aware that your box-shadow CSS won't work in IE either. Basically no CSS3 will work.

Comment: Thanks Anders. It looks better now, can see the white background with opacity BUT menu items "PLAN D'ACTIVITE" and "MEDIAS" are still overlapping. Any idea why?

Comment: @AndersHolmström I just took your answer to be as a reference in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 and earlier [can't render](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) alpha-transparency. You need to use a fallback for them (plain `#fff` would be nice imo)

Answer (score 0):

**IE8** and below versions can't render **alpha-transparency**. 
so you can use like this:

```
div {
  background-color: #xxxxxx;
  background-color: rgba(x,x,x,x);
}
```

This may help you http://css-tricks.com/ie-background-rgb-bug/

For browser supports : [click here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use CSS3 PIE for Internet Explorer 6 - 8!!!

**PIE** makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

From the Website:

> *CSS Level 3 brings with it some incredibly powerful styling features. Rounded corners, soft drop shadows, gradient fills, and so on. These are the kinds of elements our designer friends love to use because they make for attractive sites, but are difficult and time-consuming to implement, involving complex sprite images, extra non-semantic markup, large JavaScript libraries, and other lovely hacks.*

#### Check out more about implementing it for IE 8 here: http://css3pie.com/

For the Opacity, as [Anders Holmström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557127/anders-holmstrom) said, you can use `filter` in the style with a white background of the child nav elements:

```
filter: Alpha(opacity='80');
background: #fff;
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why 2 menu items are overlapping? ("PLAN d'ACTIVITE" & "MEDIAS")